# How to set workspace from input Feature Class?

Tags: arcpy

How to set workspace from input Feature Class ? is there an attribute of the source GDB for a feature class ? some times the FC is in a dataset and some time it isn't, How can i get the path of source GDB for setting workspace when the input is dynamic ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`catalogPath`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/018v00000013000000/) property of the [`Describe`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) object.

For example:

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(arcpy.Describe(feat_class).catalogPath)
desc = arcpy.Describe(dirname)
if hasattr(desc, "datasetType") and desc.datasetType=='FeatureDataset':
    dirname = os.path.dirname(dirname)
```

Comment: the catalog path function gives the path with the dataset, for setting workspace i need the path to the GDB only (without the data set)

Comment: @Geog Luke is correct. os.path.dirname() extracts the workspace out of the full path.

Comment: @Geog Use `os.path.dirname` twice. See edit.

Comment: You can also try using the path property of the Describe object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36905906/2457991